# Find coordinates using the address of the place

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a list of address (street, city, country, zip) and I want to find the lat and long to mark them in google maps.
is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I think [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

yes thanks
this is what am looking for

```
function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

}